# Defining custom URL routes in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, routedebugger

I have the following routes defined:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(name: "Homepage", url: "", defaults: new { controller = "Restaurants", action = "Search" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "About", url: "about", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "Disclaimer", url: "disclaimer", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Disclaimer" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "Contact", url: "contact", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "RestaurantDetails", url: "{id}/{slug}", defaults: new { controller = "Restaurant", action = "Details" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "RestaurantLocationDetails", url: "{id}/{restaurantSlug}/{locationSlug}", defaults: new { controller = "Restaurant", action = "LocationDetails" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "Api", url: "api/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "Api" });
}
```

I found some routes to give a 404, so I installed the RouteDebugger NuGet package.

It shows what I expect for the first 4 routs, but on the last 3 routes I still get a 404 and alas Route Debugger doesn't appear at the bottom of the page - I was hoping it would show me which bits got mapped, but I get nothing. All the views exist.

So I'm assuming I'm making a mistake with the route definitions - can anyone shed any light on this? Also, how can I get Route Debugger to show me how the URL gets mapped into the route dictionary for those pages that return a 404?

Comment: I think you need to reverse your RestaurantDetails and RestaurantLocationDetails definitions but I'm not sober so I could be wrong. And I don't know anything about routes.

Comment: +1 @Joe Phillips for admitting you're not sober :)

Comment: if you're blind (which I find amazing) you should definitely bring your issues up on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and your problems in accessing this site.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to change the order of the routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Homepage", url: "", defaults: new { controller = "Restaurants", action = "Search" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "About", url: "about", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "Disclaimer", url: "disclaimer", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Disclaimer" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "Contact", url: "contact", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "Api", url: "api/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "Api" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "RestaurantLocationDetails", url: "{id}/{restaurantSlug}/{locationSlug}", defaults: new { controller = "Restaurant", action = "LocationDetails" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "RestaurantDetails", url: "{id}/{slug}", defaults: new { controller = "Restaurant", action = "Details" });
```

The routes are processed in the order in which they're added to the route list.

For example: `api/action` also matches the `RestaurantDetails` route since there are only two parameters in the route url parameters.

So it needs to go from specific to general. In general if you have the same number of parameters in two route definitions then the first route added will be the one chosen.

Comment: Although I think the "api" part of the URL will not match the RestaurantDetails URL will it?

Comment: It will if `RestaurantDetails` is before the `Api` one because the url segment `api/action` also matches `{id}/{slug}` so if `RestaurantDetails` is before `Api` it will match first.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation. Makes sense. Putting Api above RestaurantDetails makes that work now. But I can't get restaurantDetails or restaurantLocationDetails to work - I've tried different orderings, and also specifying "" as the defaults for id/slug/etc. I also double checked that the controller/action/parameters matched the method.

Comment: Could you post your example urls (without domain). I tested them with `someid/somerestaurantslug/somelocationslug` and it matches `RestaurantLocationDetails` and `detailid/detailslug` matches the `RestaurantDetails` route

Comment: I'm wondering if you're expecting the `restaurantSlug` to be a wildcard match so that you could match `restid/restaurantslugpart1/restaurantslugpart2/locationslugpart1/locationslugpart2`

Comment: Got this working now - in addition to the order, there was another one-character typo. . @BuildStarted I really appreciate your explanation/help :-)

Comment: @Saqib, Glad to be of help :)