# asp.net mvc routing "view was not found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

very simple basic question
I have only route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Widget", // Route name
                "Widget/Frame/{postUrl}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Widget", action = "Index", postUrl = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And when i try to open following url:"http://localhost:50250/Widget/Frame/qwerty"

I have an error:

> The view 'qwerty' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:

Well...why?

Controller code:

```
public class WidgetController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Widget/

        public ActionResult Index(string postUrl, int? blogEngineType)
        {
            return View(postUrl);
        }




    }
```

Comment: Show us the controller Widget's action Frame's code.

Comment: but i havent Frame action only index. anyway see update.

Comment: See this:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118840/mvc3-and-rewrites/8255132#8255132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hazard a guess and say it's because it's actually trying to use the action name of Index(), since that's the default action that you've specified. You're not passing an {action} parameter through the url, so where else will it get the action from?

Can you change your url pattern to `Widget/{action}/{postUrl}` and see if it works then?

Either that, or set the default value of `action` to `Frame` instead. Basically, it has no way of knowing that you're looking for the `Frame` action, so it fails.

Edit: I see what you're doing now - the action's name is actually Index, right? In that case, I'm not sure, we need to see your controller code. I'll leave the above answer in case it's useful.

Edit 2: You're passing the value "qwerty" as the view name - do you have a view named "qwerty" in the views folder?

If you intend for it to be the model, and for the view name to be "Index", you should call `return View((object)postUrl);` instead, so that it doesn't get confused.

Comment: Widget/{action}/{postUrl} this doesnt work too with url:"http://localhost:50250/Widget/index/qwerty"

Comment: See my edit. The route isn't your problem, it's the view name.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a View with

```
return View(postUrl);
```

Since there is no name of the view (in this overload), the method uses the Action name as view name and looks for it. You probably meant to do

```
return Redirect(postURL);
```

Comment: Oh yees! Thanks! I actually mean return View((object)postUrl);

Answer (score 2):

It's because your return statement is `return View(postUrl);` and when you pass a string to the View() method it is interpreted as the name of the view to use. So it looks for a view called `qwerty` since that's what's in that variable. If you want to hand postUrl as a model to the view of your Index action, you'll have to change your return to be `return View("Index", postUrl)`

Comment: Or like Steve says, use `View((object)postUrl)` so it's forced to treat it as an `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is a View called 'qwerty' in the Shared or Widget folder within the Views parent folder?
Otherwise you probably want to use `return RedirectToAction(postURL);`